# change string to array

Tags: javascript, json

I retrieve the following array of string values

```
[
"Module1.resource1.create",
"Module1.resource1.read",
"Module1.resource1.update",
"Module1.resource1.delete",
...
"Module1.resourceN.create",
"Module1.resourceN.read",
"Module1.resourceN.update",
]
```

I would like to change them to json format like this

```
{"privileges": {
    "Module1": {
      "resource1": {
          "create": true,
          "read": true,
          "update": true,
          "delete": true,
      },
...
      "resourceN":  {
          "create": true,
          "read": true,
          "update": true,
    }
  }
 }
}
```

All I can think of is run a loop for each string, use `split(".")` and then somehow change it to json object. the problem I'm having is that the json is not a simple `key: value`, it's more of a `key: object: object: object: value` if that makes sense ...

I would appreciate the nudge in the right direction.

cheers

Comment: IMO the `loop and split` is the way to go

Comment: @jonatjano but not sure how to change the array to multi dimentional json... I can do `key: value`. but not sure how to do `key: object: object: key: value` if you know what I mean ...

Comment: are they always going to be in order?

Comment: @zfrisch - that cannot be guaranteed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method:

```
const result = { privileges: {} };
items.reduce((ret, el) => {
   // Split the array elements and use destructuring assignment syntax for
   // creating constants
   const [module, resource, verb] = el.split('.');
   // check if privileges[module] property exists. If not, define it as an empty object.
   if (!ret[module]) ret[module] = {};
   // follows the previous line's logic for resources!
   if (!ret[module][resource]) ret[module][resource] = {};
   ret[module][resource][verb] = true;
   return ret;
}, result.privileges);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h5q90y8k/) | [Destructuring assignment syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: that works exactly as I want it to work! thanks. However, I don't really understand what is happening there.. Is it too much to ask for some explanation? I would appreciate that.

Comment: You are welcome! I'll add some comments to the code.

Comment: thank you. It's always better to understand than just copy and paste :)

Comment: interesting. I never knew about Destructuring assignment syntax, this will come in handy  :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

May be using dot-object will help without reinventing the wheel:

https://github.com/rhalff/dot-object

Comment: Good find! Even though I think the question is more about how to achieve that from the coding side.

Answer (score 1):

This took a while, but does the job:

```js
const rules = [
    "Module1.resource1.create",
    "Module1.resource1.read",
    "Module1.resource1.update",
    "Module1.resource1.delete",
    "Module1.resourceN.create",
    "Module1.resourceN.read",
    "Module1.resourceN.update",
  ].map(rule => rule.split('.'));
  
const res = { privileges: {} };

for (const rule of rules) {
  for (i = 0; i < rule.length; i++) {
    switch (i) {
      case 0: 
        res.privileges[rule[0]] = Object.assign({}, res.privileges[rule[0]])
        break;
      case 1:
        res.privileges[rule[0]][rule[1]] = Object.assign({}, res.privileges[rule[0]][rule[1]])
        break;
      case 2:
        res.privileges[rule[0]][rule[1]][rule[2]] = true
      default:
    }
  }
}

console.log(res)
```

Comment: thank you for the effort. It indeed works as intended. I have already accepted another answer, though. Sorry. upvoted though! :)

Answer (score 0):

To do that you can use the following function:

```
function setIn(target, path, value) {
  var chain = String(path).split('.');
  while (chain.length > 0) {
    var field = chain.shift();
    if (chain.length == 0) {
      target[field] = value;
    } else if (field in target && target[field] !== null && typeof target[field] === 'object') {
      target = target[field];
    } else {
      target[field] = {}
      target = target[field];
    }
  }
  return value;
}
```

And produce the tree:

```
var tree = { privileges: {} };
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1)
  setIn(tree.privileges, array[i], true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.reduce()` for this to create your nested map. The above example will work for any level of children and will always set the last child to a boolean value.

```js
const arr = ["Module1.resource1.create","Module1.resource1.read","Module1.resource1.update","Module1.resource1.delete","Module1.resourceN.create","Module1.resourceN.read","Module1.resourceN.update","Module2.resourceN.update",];
let result = {privalages:{}};
result.privalages = arr.reduce((o, curr)=>{
  let props = curr.split(".");
  props.reduce((a, prop, index)=> a[prop] = index !== props.length-1 ?(a[prop] || {}) : true,o);
  return o;
},{});

console.log(result);
```